# Use Variable for Output of SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs a stored procedure on a server (scheduled weekly) and spits out the result, from a query in the stp, to a file to be picked up by another program.

I need the name of this output file to be the week of the year and the year in WW YY format.

My current package is basic, using a DestinationConnectionFlatFile Manager, outputing to a static name.

Any clues as to how to do this would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Select the Flat file connection manager and edit the expression to something like:

```
"C:\\" + DatePart("wk",getdate()) + " " + DatePart("year",getdate()) + ".txt"
```

These kind of expression are based on `VB`.

Comment: Should this expression be applied on the connection string property?